# Dot product between constant vector and variable with batch size in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, vector, tensorflow2.0

In tensorflow I have:

1. A constant of 2000 vectors with dimension 1500. (dim = (2000, 1500)) named X
2. A batch input variable of 75 vectors with dimension 1500 (dim = (?, 75, 1500)) named y

I want the dot product of each vector of X between each vector of y result in a vector of dimension (?, 75, 2000)

Is there a way I can do it using the dot or batch_dot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use [tf.matmul()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul). It will work on an unknown batch.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


# random X
X = tf.random.normal([2000, 1500])

print(X.shape)
# (2000, 1500)

# variable-batch y
y = tf.keras.Input([75, 1500])

print(y.shape)
# (None, 75, 1500)

# dot-product
out = tf.matmul(y, X, transpose_b=True)

print(out.shape)
# (None, 75, 2000)
```